# which java http client library is easy to use for programmatically doing posts, setting cookies and maybe ajax?

Tags: java, http, client

which java http client library is easy to use for programmatically doing posts, setting cookies and maybe ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache HTTP Component (HttpClient 4.0),

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/index.html

Normally, I would just use HttpURLConnection but its cookie handling is too weak to simulate browser behavior.

Comment: Looks like the URL has changed. Try http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JdkRequest`](http://http.jcabi.com/apidocs-1.0/com/jcabi/http/request/JdkRequest.html) from [jcabi-http](http://http.jcabi.com/) (I'm a developer), which does all this work for you, decorating `HttpURLConnection`, firing HTTP requests and parsing responses, for example:

```
new JdkRequest("http://www.google.com")
  .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .body()
  .formParam("name", "John")
  .back()
  .method("POST")
  .fetch();
```

Read this blog post for more details: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/04/11/jcabi-http-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Async request like AJAX:
  http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/

Sync request:
  http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/index.html

Cookies is A kind of Header. Add cookies like A Header:

```
"Cookie: COOKIE_1=231412;COOKIE_2=234124"
```